# Nginx ratelimitting exception

Tags: nginx

I've successfully applied rate-limiting to 1r/s in my Nginx configuration, however I want to implement a function that will apply different rate limit settings (20r/s) for whitelisted IPs. Here are the relevant config settings:

nginx.conf

```
limit_req_zone $limit zone=all:20m rate=1r/s;
```

domain.conf

```
geo $whitelist {
        default 1;
        1.1.1.1 0;
    }
    map $whitelist $limit {
        0 "";
        1 $binary_remote_addr;
    }

limit_req zone=all burst=5;
```

This works as expected, when I whitelist 1.1.1.1, I can access the website without being rate limited at all. How can I implement a limit of 20r/s for the whitelisted IPs? I understand that the solution is not to use 2 zones, but I have read the documentation several times and am at a loss as to how to implement this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In reading the [nginx.org documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html), it seems like using more than one zone is the solution, but it has been some time since I experimented with that directive, so I'm not sure why you do not want to use more than one zone.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what it should look like. Even if I add another zone called whitelist w/ 20r/s and apply limit_req zone=whitelist burst=5; Nginx is still ignoring it and ratelimitting it using the zone=all

Comment: I actually found the example https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/ but it's always hitting the req_zone_wl zone no matter what IP I whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

```
limit_req_zone $limit zone=all:20m rate=1r/s;

geo $whitelist {
        default 1;
        1.1.1.1 0;
    }
    map $whitelist $limit {
        0 "";
        1 $binary_remote_addr;
    }

limit_req_zone $whitelist zone=new:10m  rate=25r/m; burst=5;
```